# Redirect to page on button click in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component which was previously working but no longer is for some reason.

This is my container :

```
import React , {useEffect} from 'react'
import {withRouter} from "react-router-dom"
import LoginView from './LoginView'


export default withRouter(function Login(props) {
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if(localStorage.getItem('jwt')){
            props.history.push('/dashboard');
        }
    })
    
    const handleLogin = () => {
        console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_URL);
        window.location.href = process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_URL;
    }   

    return (
        <LoginView handleLogin={handleLogin}/>
    )
})
```

And my view :

```
import React from 'react'; 
import logo from '../../../assets/img/logo-red.png'
import '../Auth.css'; 

export default function LoginView({handleLogin}) {
    return (
        <div className="loginContainer">
            <div className='loginLogo'>
                <img src={logo} alt=''/>
            </div>
            <div className = "loginForm">
                <h3>Inloggen</h3>
                <div className = "loginSeparator"/>
                <p>Uitsluitend voor medewerkers en klanten van</p>
                <button className="loginBtn loginBtn--google" onClick={handleLogin}>
                   <span>Login met Google</span>
                </button>     
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

When i click on my button the handle login function gets triggered. It logs the url from my .env.local file which is: `*localhost:8000/api/auth/google*`

But this line doesnt seem to fire : `window.location.href = process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_URL;`

Comment: If it is set to a different URL than the one which you are currently on then the browser window redirects to that page

Comment: The page i am on is just localhost:3000 and i am trying to redirect to localhost:8000/api/auth/google which is my server and the url is working if i visit it manually. @Oyeme

Comment: @Kevin.a try adding http before the url in env variable

Comment: @MurliPrajapati i already tried that but with no luck sadly

Comment: Try to use window.location.replace(...)

Comment: @MurliPrajapati i tried it again and restarted the development server and now it works. Thank you so much this was giving me headache